# array of anonymous function inside a function matlab

Tags: matlab, anonymous-function

I have defined an array of anonymous functions in side a function as shown below.

```
function test(x,y)

    f={@(x,y) (3*y*x^2)
       @(x,y) (x*y)
       @(x,y) (x*2*y^2)
       @(x,y) (2*x*y)}
res2=f{2}(x,y)-2*f{1}(x,y)
res3=f{3}(x,y)-5*f{2}(x,y)
res4=f{4}(x,y)-4*f{2}(x,y))
    
end
```

I want to obtain a 3 by 10 matrix via

```
x=2
y=linspace(0.0001,0.001,10)
for i=1:length(y)
final(i)=test(x,y(i));
end
```

However, I get an error stating there are too many input variables. How could I correct this?

Comment: What are  you trying to accomplish? Your syntax doesn't make much sense. Are you expecting `test` to return three values? Make it return a 3-value vector, then say `final(:,i)=test(x,y(i))`. And do [preallocate](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/preallocating-arrays.html) `final`!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function test(x,y)
```

This function returns nothing. So in your main code, you are asking too many output arguments.

You define functions that return as:

```
function [output1, output2 , ... , outputn]=f(input1, input2, ... , inputn)
```

Not sure in your case what you want, as your main loop only captures 1 output, yet inside the function you compute 3 variables.

Comment: I would like my main loop to output res2,res3,res4 10 times based on my linspace definition, ie, 3 by 10 matrix.

Comment: @user9106985 then define `function [res2, res3, res4]=test(x,y)`, but you need to capture that output with something else, like `final(:,i)`

Comment: Thanks! I will check this later.